# How to download all my Flickr content?

Tags: software-recommendation, data-transfer, flickr

Are there any free apps to download my entire photostream from Flickr?

Or at least as much content as possible? I want to quit my Flickr account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.malarkeysoftware.com/projects_PhotoGrabbr.html

This great piece of software will do it.

Beware though, if don't have a pro account, you [can't download](http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/#28) the high resolution originals.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Bulkr - http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr. It has a one click button to backup your Flickr photostream. Also, title, tags, description and geotag info embedding into EXIF is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can give flickery a try (www.flickeryapp.com) - it's a full-featured flickr client, downloads EXIF info as far as I know and is currently on sale 48% off on the Mac App Store.